# Difference between SQL azure web and business editions?

Tags: performance, azure-sql-database

Is there any difference in SQL azure web and business editions other than the storage limits and pricing. Any one of these known to be more performant?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Azure web vs business edition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426360/sql-azure-web-vs-business-edition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same except of course storage limits and pricing.

Comment: This is my suspicion , but I was hoping to know if they were managed in different server pools or exhibited different performance characteristics. Maybe I am over analyzing this.