# what is the maximum Size of .sql file that can be uploaded to sql azure management portal???

Tags: azure-storage

I am trying to run the .sql file in SQL AZURE MANAGEMENT PORTAL. The size of the .sql file is 9.3GB. When I try to open it, I could not. Please tell what is the maximum size of .sql file that can be opened and executed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your 9.3 GB is a problem.

please read

[Azure SQL Database Web vs Business Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426360/sql-azure-web-vs-business-edition)

Comment: Thanks...I read.. That is why I had chosen "Business" edition... So, you say that the size of  .sql file doesnt matter?

Comment: exactly. the size of .sql file is not a factor for not being able to execute it for 9.3GB (for business edition, up to 150GB is supported)

Comment: well.. dude your question was "what is the max size.." If you want to solve your problem (as i said it is not about sql file size due to capability of supporting up to 150GB) you need to ask a new question with more and more detail. This question is too vague and answered, I think.