# Cannot get Linked Servers to work in Sql Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We are using a trial version of Azure. We are trying to perform cross server queries from our SQL Server 2012 in-house.

We seem to have our local 2012 linked with Azure. When I go into `Server Object` -> `Linked Servers` in management studio, I see our `Azure` database.

But if I try to open the catalog and tables, I get an error message saying

> Reference to database and/or server name in 'Perseus.sys.sp_tables_rowset2'  is not supported in this version of SQL Server

** **Perseus** is the name of our catalog in `Azure Sql`.

Running a query from local connection:

```
SELECT *  FROM [azureDBServer].[Perseus].[dbo].[accounts]
```

Tesult is:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "azureDBServer" returned message
> "Unspecified error". Msg 40515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Reference to database and/or
> server name in 'Perseus.sys.sp_tables_info_90_rowset' is not supported in this version of
> SQL Server.

This same in house SQL 2012 Server is able to connect to our in-house 2008 by cross server queries and by viewing its structure through Linked Servers.

I know from this article [Azure supports Linked Servers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/09/19/announcing-updates-to-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx).

So I'm lost about what is wrong. Our Admin thinks it may be that we have a Web-Sql account vs a business SQL account. This [Azure Web vs Business SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426360/sql-azure-web-vs-business-edition) outdated Stack link implies that SQL version is NOT the problem, but pre-dates when Azure offered Linked Servers.

So, I'm trying to understand if

**a)** we didn't set up something right to provide SQL Linking?

**b)** we are limited by trial?

**c)** are we limited by Web SQL version?

**d)** anything else?

Comment: Is Azure the source or target for the linked server? I believe it only works if Azure is the target from an on-premise SQL Server.

Comment: @Jaxidian Correct, Azure is target and while Azure is registered under our in-house server's `Linked Servers`, we are unable to Cross-read from Azure through our in-house 2012

Comment: @Jaxidian, yes, we also tried a simple cross server query. see my edit

Comment: Your edit came just as I sent that so I immediately deleted it. ;-) Next question, what roles does the user/login have that you're connecting with?

Comment: @Jaxidian, the user is admin (dbo)

Comment: I'm not sure what else might be the problem. That said, I'm by no means an expert here and could just as easily be missing something like you are. I can, with some confidence, say: b) Trial Azure account shouldn't limit you in any way here unless it's with a Preview feature c) I don't think Web SQL vs Business SQL has any functional differences at this time. Have you tried a purely scripted connection similar to the guide you linked? If that doesn't work, can you share a clean version of that script?

Comment: @Jaxidian, before we tried a script, we simply tried a basic query (varbatim what's posted). Agree, cannot see any issue. Was hoping it would be trial, at least that's something I can fix... That said, I wonder about the complaint about **version**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While adding linked server from SQL Management, you are not given option to set default database. So use something like below

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server='name for referring locally', -- here you can specify the name of the linked server
@srvproduct='',     
@provider='sqlncli', -- using SQL Server native client
@datasrc='AzureMachineName.database.windows.net',   -- add here your server name
@location='',
@provstr='',
@catalog='yourdatabasename'
```

I figured this works.

Comment: I get the error: Could not find Stored procedure 'sp_addlinkedserver'. Also using Azure sql db.

Comment: with this, you need to go in linked server and in security menu add your user along with the password in format like "user@url.database.windows.net" then you are good to connect

Answer (score 41):

Need to execute below mentioned three stored procedures to add SQL Azure. Using below these stored procedure I was able to query SQL azure.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server='PROD',
@srvproduct='',     
@provider='sqlncli',
@datasrc='azureserver.database.windows.net',
@location='',
@provstr='',
@catalog='database name'


EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
@rmtsrvname = 'PROD',
@useself = 'false',
@rmtuser = 'Azure login',
@rmtpassword = 'password'

EXEC sp_serveroption 'PROD', 'rpc out', true
```

Comment: Might I just add that server = 'PROD' was just the same as the datasource value in my case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Excellent! just what I needed

Comment: Your my man of the day!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't actually set up a connection to the Perseus database.  From the error message it looks like you are sending a query with 3 part or 4 part name to Azure.  That doesn't work in Azure.

Please check your query and set it to use 2 part name and only three part name if it is connecting to the same database.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mypassword';
 
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MySecurity 
WITH IDENTITY = 'mylogin',
SECRET = 'mypassword';
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyDbAccess
WITH (
    TYPE=RDBMS,
    LOCATION='server name',
    DATABASE_NAME='db_name',
    CREDENTIAL= MySecurity);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MyExtTable (
    [Id] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar(20)] NULL)
WITH
(DATA_SOURCE = MyDbAccess);
```

After that you can just use it:

```
SELECT * FROM MyExtTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and my issue ended up being a type in the database name `SERVER.Database.dbo.tableName`.