# copy table content to same table on other sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database, database-migration

I have used the wizard from http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ to move my database from:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64) 
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (VM)
```

to

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 11.0.9164.122
```

Which worked great, but there was a table with over a gigabyte of rubbish data. So I stopped the process. Now it copied a table structure, but forgot to fill the content. I will have to fix this manually with query:

```
-- when connected to the azure db
select into azureDb.dbo.tablename select * onPremisesServer.onPremisesDb.dbo.tablename
```

But when I execute it, I get:

> Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Reference to database and/or server name in 'onPremisesServer.onPremisesDb.dbo.tablename' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

I have found [Cannot get Linked Servers to work in Sql Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403129/cannot-get-linked-servers-to-work-in-sql-azure) and it says that it is client related. So I looked up my version of SSMS:

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3128.0

So that cannot cause this. I have also had troubles with the 'onPremisesServer' being just an ip address and had to execute `select name from sys.servers` to find a server alias instead of using [ipadres] for onPremisesServer. Still cannot get it to work. The tables have exactly the same schema.

**edit** as DeicLone123 mentioned, I used import and export data. I have renamed the table to tablename-old on azure and ran the wizard and got:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the SSMS import/export wizard? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Comment: Server to server did not work, and export to csv and import is hard because you have to set column types etc. manually

Comment: SQL Server Azure needs to have all tables with clustered indexes. Add a clustered index to the table.

You will find information about how to create clustered indexes here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx#cir

and here: http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/creating-nonclustered-indexes-on-massive-tables-in-windows-azure-sql-database/

Comment: But I have a clustered index which is my autoincrement int primary key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the 3.x again from http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ to migrate just that last table. Easy as that! Manually transferring the data, column types etc. is a real pain.. So this open source migration tool is really recommended!