# Windows Azure and SQL Server on VM (which choose to compare)

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I'd like to compare Windows Azure SQL Database and SQL Server on VM. So I'd like to ask: 
which SQL server edition on Windows Azure(S,M edition; Web or Standard) should I choose to compare it with Windows Azure SQL Database Web. I know that these are different concepts PaaS IaaS and so on. In my question I am referring to your experience with these two technologies and their performance. I know that it would be roughly comparison

Comment: in that case you can compare any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, [Windows Azure SQL Database](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/data-management/) is comparable to the features of [SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx), but this comparison is only approximate, because each offer is meant for a different use case and offers a different balance of features.

In [Understanding Azure SQL Database and SQL Server in Azure VMs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-management-azure-sql-database-and-sql-server-iaas/) you'll find a detailed comparison. Some distinctive characteristics are:

- SQL Database is highly available; each database is backed by 3 servers; each operation will only be completed when it is accepted by at least 2 servers. This leads to a higher latency than SQL Server on a single server.
- SQL Database runs on cloud infrastructure. Client applications must be fault-tolerant.
- SQL Database runs on shared resources, so clients may experience performance fluctuations. The [Premium Offer for Windows Azure SQL Database](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2013/07/09/a-closer-look-at-the-premium-offer-for-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx) delivers more powerful and predictable performance.
- SQL Database has a few [limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394102.aspx) on support for [features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394115.aspx), [Transact-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336250.aspx), [Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336233.aspx) and [Tools and Utilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621784.aspx).

See also how to [Compare SQL Server with Windows Azure SQL Database](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/996.compare-sql-server-with-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx) and the guidance on [SQL Server in Windows Azure Virtual Machines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj823132.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I made comparison for Azure SQL and SQL Server Std hosted on Azure VM (Large (A3)) for 2GB database. I just copied DB from Azure to VM, so, basically, I had 2 Databases with identical data and was able to run same queries.

SQL Azure DB has known advantages, but when it goes to performance people starts crying:

- Getting last 1000 transactions from ~100k transactions with many joins takes:

  > Azure SQL: 7:40 mins
  >
  > SQLServer on VM: 2:30 mins
- Getting 10 transactions with specific parameter's:

  > Azure SQL: 3:57 mins
  >
  > SQLServer on VM: 1:05 mins

In this test I didn't care about query performance, I just want to see the difference for the same data/queries between Azure SQL and SQL Server on Azure VM. As you see, it's very differ.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Windows Azure SQL Database Web edition: Web and Business editions are identical except for storage capacity (see my detailed SO answer about this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521506/272109)), so it doesn't matter for your comparison.

Regarding SQL Server editions, I think this is going to be primarily a [difference in features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) and licensing, not performance. That said: If you choose the Enterprise edition, you may find more features are active, therefore consuming more resources. Fortunately the Web, Standard, and Enterprise editions are all in the Virtual Machine gallery, so you can deploy any of them without having to do a custom install.

When comparing Windows Azure SQL Database with SQL Server, you should probably start with [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336279.aspx) which goes into detail about the limitations of SQL Database as well as T-SQL differences.